# Why sometimes get different results when using WebFonts?

Tags: fonts, webfonts, charset

I am using PuppeteerSharp which deployed to Azure Linux Functions by using below WebFonts. I cannot guarantee the output of PDF that printed all characters from different languages.

```
$font-family: Arial-Unicode-MS,myanmar3,Noto-Sans-Khmer;


@font-face{
  font-family:"Arial-Unicode-MS";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-display: swap;
  src:url('fonts/Arial-Unicode-MS.woff2') format("woff2");
}
@font-face{
  font-family:"myanmar3";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-display: auto;
  src:url('fonts/myanmar3.woff2') format("woff2");
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Noto-Sans-Khmer';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-display: auto;
  src: url('fonts/noto-sans-khmer-v9-khmer-regular.woff2') format('woff2');
}
```

However, the printed PDFs are with different output:

**Case1: Most of times printed PDF with Latin characters only:**

[image]

**Case2: Missing Khmer character:**

[image]

**Case3: Printed all languages characters:**

[image]

Comment: If you print from html to pdf, it should be OK but here what is your solution to print Khmer text here?

Comment: hi @Osify, my solution is to used Azure Linux Function with Customer image (install fonts in docker image).

Answer (score 1):

Can you please specify the Unicode range of each font as example for Khmer text, use this range `unicode-range: U+1780-17FF, U+200C, U+25CC;`

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Noto-Sans-Khmer';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-display: auto;
  src: url('fonts/noto-sans-khmer-v9-khmer-regular.woff2') format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+1780-17FF, U+200C, U+25CC;
}
```

and do the same for other language in the CSS, that would work.

And for linux case, you should have install the font in your system.

Comment: Thanks @Osify. I changed to use docker image to install required fonts in dockerfile.